# Memory leak in c++ found with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

I'm having problems with delete on c++. I'm not sure if I understand when I leak memory and when I don't. But according to Visual Studio there are leaks.

Is this leaking memory? The actual method is bigger and I want to use c as part of an struct.

```
char *c=copio("hola");
char *copio(char * c1)
{
    char * ret=new char[strlen(c1)+1];
    strcpy(ret,c1);
    return ret;
};
```

And this? In this case aux is auxiliar, so I don't use it when I leave the big method

```
archivo *aux=ultimoArchivo(m->listaArchivos);
archivo * ultimoArchivo(archivo* lista){
    if(lista==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        if(lista->sig==NULL){
            return lista;
        }else{
            return ultimoArchivo(lista->sig);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information here to decide if you leak memory or not. If you never delete the memory allocated by `copio`, then yes, you leak it. That said, there's no reason to be using `char*` as a string or writing your own linked list, just use the standard library.

Comment: Oh dear. You're using C++ without using a proper `string` class? Any reason for that?

Comment: Have you considered using C++11 smart pointers?

Comment: It is a school project and we are not allowed to use any of that stuff. But thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you have to make sure that after you're done using the pointer returned by `copio` you delete it, otherwise you end up with a memory leak. But as the others said, unless this is an exercise, use `std::string` for string manipulation, or, if not, at least declare your own class and do the `delete` in the destructor (or use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, i.e. a smart pointer).

I don't understand your second code snippet, it looks like there are no allocations there so don't know how you can end up with a memory leak.